# bash: how to construct quoted arguments from file or array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to construct a set of arguments to pass on a command. Arguments are like so:

```
cmd --option 'a b c' --option 'd e f' ...
```

I've tried every possible combination of quoting I can imaging without luck. See for example those failed tries. (Let's say that option is -1 and cmd is ls for reproducibility)

```
x[0]="-1 'a b c'"
x[1]="-1 'koko d e > f'"

set -x
ls "${x[@]}"
set +x
```

This produces:

```
+ ls '-1 '\''a b c'\''' '-1 '\''koko d e > f'\'''
ls: invalid option -- ' '
```

I've also tried putting the arguments in a file:
file x: `-1 'a b c' -1 'koko d e > f'`

and then

```
ls `cat x`
++ cat x
+ ls --color=auto -1 ''\''a' b 'c'\''' -1 ''\''koko' d e '>' 'f'\'''
ls: cannot access 'a: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access b: No such file or directory
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't combine an option and its arguments into a single word; your program expects the argument to an option to be a separate word.

```
options=("--option" "a b c" "--option" "d e f")
cmd "${options[@]}"
```

Your `ls` example is a little confusing: `-1` doesn't need to be repeated, as it isn't taking the following word as an argument. `> f` is not an argument to the command; it is shell syntax and should not be combined with the other options.

Comment: Note that some programs may accept the syntax "--option=a b c" as a single argument.

Comment: `--option=a b c` would still be 3 separate arguments, unless quoted as `--option="a b c"`. I suppose `"--option=a b c"` might be one argument; I'm not familiar with exactly how such a word is typically parsed. (Is everything on the right of the `=` considered the value of the option on the left?)

Comment: Yes, everything on the right of the `=` (to the end of that argument) is considered part of that argument; for example, in `rsync --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'` the filter is "dir-merge /.rsync-filter". Also, `"--option=a b c"`, `--option="a b c"`, `--option=a\ b\ c`, and even `--option=a" "b' 'c` all do the same thing (the shell removes the quotes/escapes before it's passed to the actual program, so the program receives exactly the same argument from all 4 variations).

Comment: Yep of course, I was stuck, thanks for this! Btw the >f is indeed an argument, it's not the shell redirection :-)

Comment: You have a file named `>f`? Eww? :)

Comment: @chepner Not a file, just an argument. Like 'version > 3' :-)